# How to get firebase data depending the data that I send before in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from firebase depending the data that I send before. For example,

I have a Textfield with a controler who is going to send the the data of the controller as you can se here

Here is the textField

```
Expanded(
                                          child: TextField(
                                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                              border: InputBorder.none,
                                              hintText: 'Type your message...',
                                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.grey[500]),
                                            ),
                                            controller: queryController,
                                            textInputAction:
                                                TextInputAction.send,
                                            onSubmitted: (msg) {
                                              // this.addMessage();
                                              this.getResponse();
                                              this.addUserMessage();
                                            },
                                          ),
                                        ),
```

Here is where I add the data to firebase:

```
  addUserMessage() {
    if (queryController != null) {
      Map<String, String> userMessageData = {
        "sendBy": Constants.myName,
        "message": queryController.text,
        //'time': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      };

      databaseMethods.adduserPrivateChat(userMessageData, Constants.myEmail);
    } else {}
  }
```

So the idea is that for example the user send something like that:

- Hi Im the user and I have brown eyes

I need to check from the firebase database any entries that has for example 'brown eyes', first check, then get and finally save. I dont know how the check and get that specific data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to find document(s) that match a certain condition.

But Firestore's queries are not meant as a text search engine, so you'll also want to look at using an additional engine for that - such as Algolia that is shown in the Firestore documentation on [implementing text search](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search).

Comment: yep, that makes sense, I think that I can use my aplication with mysql too, and may be with that I can use some other search engine, any way, thank you for your response